# UITabBarController with UIViewControllers and UITableViewControllers

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, storyboard, uitableview

I'm creating is a Storyboard app. The Main controller is a `UITabBarController`.

[image]

When the Mail and the Documents tabs are clicked, they show the respective ViewController. However when the Mail tab is clicked, I want to display `UITableViewController` with a Navigation bar. Since you cannot display a Navigation bar in a `UITableViewController`, I found out that I must add a `UINavigationController` and implement a `UITableViewController` inside it.

Can anyone please tell me how to do that? I researched here on SO as well and came across similar questions but some of them didn't have any code examples and others were for older iOS versions(I'm using iOS 6).

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Xcode contains a great way of adding in navigation and tab bar controllers – though it’s a little bit hidden away. First, select the view controller and go to the **Editor** menu -> **Embed In** -> **Navigation Controller**.

Comment: I actually knew of the Embed feature, I didn't realize i could be used here! Still a noob to iOS dev. Anyway thanks a ton, man. :)